# boto - 'AWSQueryConnection' object has no attribute 'get_signature'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I was using [this](http://jjinux.blogspot.co.il/2009/06/python-amazon-product-advertising-api.html) article in order to painlessly establish a connection to the AWS product advertising API, to convert some products UPC codes to their corresponding ASIN (Amazon-only identifier).
Basically copied the code, and did the needed modifications.

But to my great surprise the following exception got thrown to the console after running the file:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "amazon_asin_convertor.py", line 48, in <module>
        print get_data(upc[0])
      File "amazon_asin_convertor.py", line 36, in get_data
        qs, signature = aws_conn.get_signature(params, verb, path)
    AttributeError: 'AWSQueryConnection' object has no attribute 'get_signature'
```

Full code:

```
import time
import urllib
import AWS_connection

from boto.connection import AWSQueryConnection

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '****'
AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG = 'my_tag'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '***'

#init relational db connection
AWS_connection.startRDSConnection()
conn = AWS_connection.getConnection()
cursor = conn.cursor()


def get_data(upc):
    aws_conn = AWSQueryConnection(
        aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, is_secure=False,
        host='ecs.amazonaws.com')
    aws_conn.SignatureVersion = '2'
    params = dict(
        Service='AWSECommerceService',
        Version='2008-08-19',
        SignatureVersion=aws_conn.SignatureVersion,
        AWSAccessKeyId=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        AssociateTag=AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG,
        Operation='ItemLookup',
        IdType='UPC',
        ItemId=upc,
        ResponseGroup='ItemAttributes,Images',
        Timestamp=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime()))
    verb = 'GET'
    path = '/onca/xml'
    qs, signature = aws_conn.get_signature(params, verb, path)
    qs = path + '?' + qs + '&Signature=' + urllib.quote(signature)
    print "verb:", verb, "qs:", qs
    response = aws_conn._mexe(verb, qs, None, headers={})
    return response.read()


sql = "SELECT upc_code FROM supplements_table"
cursor.execute(sql)
upcs = cursor.fetchall()

for upc in upcs:
    print get_data(upc[0])
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I had the same problem...

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Not yet - I'll update if I do.

Comment: No luck - I noticed there's also a AWSAuthConnection, which sounded more promising, but couldn't get it to work...